# How to create a MySQL 5.6 Rank with JOIN and multiple sorting criteria

Tags: mysql, sql, ranking

I am stuck trying to return the rank of an SQL query.

```
SELECT c.id, c.score, i.sheetscore, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
FROM chart c LEFT JOIN indicator as i
ON c.indicator_id = i.id, (
SELECT @curRank :=0
) q
ORDER BY c.score DESC, i.sheetscore DESC
;
```

The final row should show the rank of the sorting that is presented correctly. I should be seeing Rank = 1,2,3 but I get this instead ... I've tried numerous variations of the SQL statement but I cannot strike on the solution.

```
'ID','SCORE','SHEETSCORE', 'RANK'
'11767', '1', '0.7325', '11767'
'11765', '1', '0.7325', '11765'
'8365', '1', '0.6925', '8365'
'8363', '1', '0.6925', '8363'
'8615', '1', '0.6875', '8615'
'8617', '1', '0.6875', '8617'
'11646', '1', '0.685455', '11646'
'11647', '1', '0.685455', '11647'
```

Ideally, I would use this query to:

```
SELECT RANK from Chart where ID= 11646  ## as an example
```

Comment: Consider upgrading to MySQL 8+.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - I'm constrained by my Windows Dev setup ... also my provider still supports 5.7.23 only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend joining and ordering in a subquery first, then computing the rank. Also, you should not mix implicit and explicit joins - matter of fact, always use explicit joins:

```
SELECT x.*, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
FROM (
    SELECT c.id, c.score, i.sheetscore
    FROM chart c 
    LEFT JOIN indicator i ON c.indicator_id = i.id
    ORDER BY c.score DESC, i.sheetscore DESC
) x
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @curRank :=0) q
ORDER BY score DESC, sheetscore DESC
```

Note that, if you are running MySQL 8.0, this is straight-forward with `row_number()`:

```
SELECT 
    c.id, 
    c.score, 
    i.sheetscore, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY c.score DESC, i.sheetscore DESC) rn
FROM chart c 
LEFT JOIN indicator i ON c.indicator_id = i.id
ORDER BY c.score DESC, i.sheetscore DESC
```

Comment: How would you use this script to accomplish the second part of the question ? `select * from <<this script>> where c.id = 8615` for example? When I add WHERE before the last ORDER BY, I will always get rank = 1

Answer (score 0):

**Another Option:**

A very inefficient method for determining one or two items, but a good solution for those who are working with PANDAS and Python and have many similar queries, is to download your SQL query to a Dataframe and then use Pandas' Rank and query tools - in 2 steps:

**Step 1** - Run @GMB 's answer from above:

```
conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                       database='db',
                       user='user',
                       password='pass')
cur = conn.cursor()    
rank_scores = """SELECT x.*, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
                            FROM (
                                SELECT c.id, c.score, i.sheetscore
                                FROM chart c 
                                LEFT JOIN indicator i ON c.indicator_id = i.id
                                ORDER BY c.score DESC, i.sheetscore DESC
                            ) x
                            CROSS JOIN (SELECT @curRank :=0) q
                            ORDER BY score DESC, sheetscore DESC ;"""
 df_scorerank = pd.read_sql(rank_scores, conn)
 conn.close()
 cur.close()
```

**Step 2** - extract the Rank(s) you need from the Pandas dataframe:

```
chart_rank = df_scorerank.loc[df_scorerank['id'] == chart_id, 'rank'].item()
```

As above, the dataframe now contains:

```
'ID','SCORE','SHEETSCORE', 'RANK'
'11767', '1', '0.7325', '1'
'11765', '1', '0.7325', '2'
'8365', '1', '0.6925', '3'
'8363', '1', '0.6925', '4'
'8615', '1', '0.6875', '5'
'8617', '1', '0.6875', '6'
'11646', '1', '0.685455', '7'
'11647', '1', '0.685455', '8'
```